# GetTextResource method of IMvxResourceLoader throwing Exception

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to create an iOS project that is using the mvvmcross framework.  I've been given the project that works on Windows and I'm trying to get it work on iOS.  When I run the code, I'm running into a problem that seems basic but can't seem to figure it out.

Below is the code

```
public Models.Config GetAppConfig()
    {
        var configResourceLoaded = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxResourceLoader>();
        string configText = string.Empty;
        try
        { 
            configText = configResourceLoaded.GetTextResource("Assets/AppData/Config.json");
        }
        catch (Exception noFile) {
            string f = "ff";
            f = f + "ff";
        }

        var serializer = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonConverter>();
        return serializer.DeserializeObject<Models.Config>(configText);
    }
```

The line `configText = configResourceLoaded.GetTextResource("Assets/AppData/Config.json");` causes the code to throw an exception `"Cannot load resource "Assets/AppData/Config.json""`.

I've included that folder structure in my iOS project (similar folder structure exists in Windows project).

I've tried setting Build Action for the Config.json file to both 'Content' and 'BundleResource' but it still doesn't work.

Also, in my Setup.cs, to register the `IMvxResourceLoader` I have the following code.

```
Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxResourceLoader, MvxTouchResourceLoader>();
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  Why won't it load the file?

Comment: I would try adding more `f`'s in your catch, that is probably what causes the problem...

Comment: Build Action of `Content` should work - maybe try a clean and build. If that doesn't work, maybe compare to a sample project - e.g. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Babel/Babel.Touch/Babel.Touch.csproj#L88

Answer (score 0):

`IMvxResourceLoader` uses `IMvxFileStore`. Looking at the method you are using calls `FullPath`. Looking closer at that reveals that [it looks like this](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Plugins/Cirrious/File/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.Touch/MvxTouchFileStore.cs):

```
public const string ResScheme = "res:";
protected override string FullPath(string path)
{
    if (path.StartsWith(ResScheme))
        return path.Substring(ResScheme.Length);

    return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), path);
}
```

So unless you prepend your path with `res:` it expects you are looking in `MyDocuments`.

Change your path to:

```
res:/Assets/AppData/Config.json
```